# How to find the maximal volume of a rectangular parallelepiped?

Tags: calculus

Find the volume of the largest rectangular parallelepiped that has three faces in the coordinate planes and one vertex in the plane $x+2y+3z=4$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the AM/GM inequality. Very simple, and has the added benefit of showing that the critical point is an absolute maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$\frac xa+\frac yb +\frac zc=1$$ be a plane, then $xyz$ has an extreme value if $(x,y,z)=1/3(a,b,c)$ (using Lagrange).  Somewhat nice.

Michael